Hypothesis testing upper bound involving $\chi^2$ distance
In this [note]https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture27.pdf, the author provides some upper bounds for hypothesis testing involving total variation distance and Hellinger distance in section 4. And he also mentioned that there are also such kinds of bounds involving $\chi^2$ distance but it is not provided in this note.
Can anyone provide some references about that?
